# Are Shaders used in the latest OpenGL very early?

Tags: opengl

When i look to the 4th Edition of the Book "OpenGL SuperBible" it starts with Points / Lines drawing Polygons and later on Shaders are discussed. In the 6th Edition of the book, it starts directly with Shaders as the very first example. I didn't use OpenGL for a long time, but is it the way to start with Shaders?

Why is there the shift, is this because of going from fixed pipeline to Shaders?

Comment: The fixed function pipeline has been deprecated since GL3.0 in 2008 and _removed_ from GL core profiles with GL3.2 in 2009. The programmable pipeline was introduced with GL2.0 in 2004. And as that became widely availble in 2006, there really was no real point in using the fixed function pipeline any more. So shaders are definitively the way to go, and you have to use them if you want to get anything rendered with modern GL, hence it makes sense to introduce them early.

Comment: Is there a link which states, what really has changed? Consider, someone just wants to draw Points and Dotted Lines, this was easy before GL3.0

Comment: Well, I'm not really aware of such documents (but I never looked for it). However, most of the modern GL tutorials like [open.gl](http://open.gl) or [arcsynthesis](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) introduce simple color shaders quite early. You definitively need some more "boilerplate" code to get something on the screen with modern GL, but it isn't really more complicated once you got the basic concepts (shaders,VBOs,VAOs).

Comment: In modern OpenGL shaders are the only way to draw something. You can't draw anything at all without using shaders (explicitly or hidden in a library code). And OpenGL is all about drawing things, so it would make no sense to say that shaders are introduced too early...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a limited extent it depends on exactly which branch of OpenGL you're talking about. OpenGL ES 2.0 has no path to the screen other than shaders — there's no matrix stack, no option to draw without shaders and none of the fixed-pipeline bonded built-in variables. WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0 so it inherits all of that behaviour.

As per derhass' comment, all of the fixed stuff is deprecated in modern desktop GL and you can expect it to vanish over time. The quickest thing to check is probably the [OpenGL 4.4 quick reference card](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengl44-quick-reference-card.pdf). If the functionality you want isn't on there, it's not in the latest OpenGL.

As per your comment, Kronos defines OpenGL to be:

> the only cross-platform graphics API that enables developers of
>   software for PC, workstation, and supercomputing hardware to create
>   high- performance, visually-compelling graphics software applications,
>   in markets such as CAD, content creation, energy, entertainment, game
>   development, manufacturing, medical, and virtual reality.

It more or less just exposes the hardware. The hardware can't do anything without shaders. Nobody in the industry wants to be maintaining shaders that emulate the old fixed functionality forever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it true, that with the latest Oopen GL there is no "programmable fixed-function pipeline" and there are "fixed-function stages" like for example the "vertex fetching" stage before the vertex shader is called? Are this definitions correct?

Comment: @user1767754 It's not clear what are you asking. `Fixed-function pipeline` is deprecated and in some versions totally removed. `Programmable pipeline` is the way to go and no, there are very little things that are "fixed". For example, the concept of vertexes and interpolation of data in between them.

Comment: I would almost rather maintain the fixed-function pipeline than deal with all the weird and hard to test things people can do with the programmable pipeline ;) Parsing the shader language alone is more complicated than maintaining some feature set frozen fixed-function operations using shaders. You would have a hard time selling anyone on the introduction of any significant ***new*** fixed-function features (*technically tessellation is partly fixed-function*), but maintaining the extraordinarily simple existing stuff's not so bad... most of it can be easily layered on top of anything modern.

Answer (score 2):

"*About the only rendering you can do with OpenGL without shaders is clearing a window, which should give you a feel for how important they are when using OpenGL.*"  - From OpenGL official guide

After OpenGL 3.1, the fixed-function pipeline was removed and shaders became mandatory.

So the SuperBible or the OpenGL Redbook begin by describing the new Programmable Pipeline early in discussions.  Then they tell how to write and use a vertex and fragment shading program.

For your shader objects you now have to:

1. Create the shader (glCreateShader, glShaderSource)
2. Compile the shader source into an object (glCompileShader)
3. Verify the shader (glGetShaderInfoLog)

Then you link the shader object into your shader program:

1. Create shader program (glCreateProgram)
2. Attach the shader objects (glAttachShader)
3. Link the shader program (glLinkProgram)
4. Verify (glGetProgramInfoLog)
5. Use the shader (glUseProgram)

There is more to do now before you can render than in the previous fixed function pipeline.  No doubt the programmable pipeline is more powerful, but it does make it more difficult just to begin rendering.  And the shaders are now a core concept to learn.

Comment: What is more, the way shaders *have to be* written changed significantly around the time of 3.1. There used to be a stop-gap `ftransform (...)` function you could put into a vertex shader to reproduce the old fixed-function transform with no real understanding of what it does; that no longer exists. Now you have to know a bit more about coordinate space transformation to write a "Hello World" shader.